# Stop mobile menu from disappearing on scroll - WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, navigation

I am having a difficult time figuring out why my mobile menu disappears after you begin scrolling. Any ideas on how to fix it. Thank you so much in advance. I have searched everywhere.

http://02ebe12.netsolhost.com/

Comment: On what type of platform is your page created, or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css in your active theme style.css file

```
@media(max-width:767px){
.top-wrap .header-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
}
```